# JK flip-flop and sequence network

Tags: digital-logic, clock, flipflop, counter

State diagram of the sequence network S looks like the following for a jk flip-flop:

[image]

Is this the right truth table for it?

```
           In1   I0
q1q0 -0   0-   -1  1-
 00  00   00   01  01
 01  11   11   01  01
 11  10   10   10  10
 10  11   00   00  11
```

Comment: What you meant by `1-`? Sorry I haven't seen this notation in state diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

We go from the state STAR ---> LOAD if we give q1 = 1 and various q0 (blue). Then we create two separate tables for JK .... Follow the diagram :)